# Case when in where statement parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
select docket_number,aging from (
    select docket_number, 
        sum(cast(dateDiff("mi",assigned,coalesce(completed,getdate()))/60.00 as decimal(20,2))) aging

    from ft_details_h 

    group by docket_number
)a where aging case  when  @hh <= 72 then  <= @hh else  > @hh end
```

hi guys how can i satisfy the where statement when the parameter @hh is less than or = to 72 the where statement should be aging <= @hh and when the aging is greater than 72 the where statement should be aging >@hh

Comment: There's a 'dead zone' with this kind of condition. Don't know what type is `aging` but let's suppose it's an `int`. Also let `aging = 73` and `@hh = 73`. Is a row with this `aging` going to be selected? Let's see. `@hh <= 72`? No, 73 is *not* less than or equal to 72. `aging > @hh`? 73 is *not* greater than 73, so again, **no**. I think, it should be (using the original pseudo-code) `where aging case  when  @hh <= 72 then  <= @hh else >= @hh end`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
where 
    (@hh <= 72 and aging <= @hh) or
    (@hh > 72 and aging > @hh)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote your question, try:

```
   where (aging <= @hh And @hh <= 72) Or 
         (aging > @hh And aging > 72)
```

but Im suspicious you have a typo and actually meant

```
   where (aging <= @hh And @hh <= 72) Or 
         (aging > @hh  And @hh > 72)
```